# Formatting a Javascript counter into 00:26

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have some Javascript code that is basically an "elapsed" timer for a file upload. Here's the code:

```
// Update elapsed
var time = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
var elapsed = Math.floor(time / 100) / 10;
console.log(elapsed);
```

Using this, I get logs in the console looking like: `0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2` etc. These are seconds and the number after the `.` is 10ths of a second. I want to format this into a more human readable form, for example, 26 seconds would be `00:26`, 1 minute 30 seconds would be `01:30`, 20 minutes would be `20:00` etc.

However, I've got no idea how I can properly write a function to convert it into a human readable form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert time string format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991257/convert-time-string-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/69dgJ/1/

```
function formatSecs(secs) {
    secs = parseInt(secs);
    ss = secs % 60;
    mm = Math.floor(secs / 60.0);
    if(ss < 10) { ss = "0" + ss; }
    if(mm < 10) { mm = "0" + mm; }
    fmt = mm + ":" + ss;
    return fmt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sprintf() for Javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) and format your output properly. If you have used `sprintf` in other languages, it should be trivial

Comment: This wouldn't really be that helpful as he would still need to convert 90 seconds to 1 minute, 30 seconds.

Comment: that's a trivial math function with modulo arithmetic!